# Using ALL the analog pins on Mega for Servo

Tags: arduino-mega, servo, analogwrite

I wish to use ALL the Analog pins on a Mega2560 R3 to control Servo's, all is well up to and including A9, but from there on nothing. {sound familiar} this is apparently not a new problem. I have tried Servo.h and MegaServo.h but still no luck, does anyone have info on a library that will do this or a method to get around it........all the pins on the end buss are used for other purposes and are not available. I can post the code, but first just asking the general questions. Thanks Doug

Answer (score 1):

OK..Solved...tried a library I had previously discarded for another project but it works with this situation..SoftwareServo ....(had also tried versions of Servo and MegaServo with no luck) I have attached a proven sketch that shows the method using arrays (as i have 16 servos to control) hope this is of use to others.

```
    /*This sketch will enable you to use ALL of the Analog pins on a Mega2560 to control a Servo
 * it uses the Arrays and the Softwareservo.h as the other Servo libraries do not support 
 * Mega Analog above A9
 * this is the only method i have found that works 
 * hope this is of use to others.
 */
#include <SoftwareServo.h> 

SoftwareServo servos[16];  // create servo object to control a servo 

int pos=0;
int servoPins[] = {A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,A10,A11,A12,A13,A14,A15};                    //servo pin numbers
int servoPosMin[] = {80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,89,80,81,80,70,80,45};                        //servo lower setting to suit individual servo
int servoPosMax[] = {100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,110,100,160};        //servo upper setting to suit individual servo  
boolean refresh = false;  // toggle refresh on/off
int m = 0;
int p = 0;
void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for (m=0;m < 16;m++) {
      // attaches the servo on pin to the servo object
    servos[m].attach(servoPins[m]);                  
      // init angle of servo inbetween two limitations
    servos[m].write(((servoPosMax[m]+servoPosMin[m])/2));
    Serial.println(m);
    delay(10);
      SoftwareServo::refresh();
  } 
}
void loop() 
{
  for (p=0;p < 16;p++) {

    for (pos = servoPosMin[p]; pos <= servoPosMax[p]; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
      servos[p].write(pos);                                       // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(15);                                                  // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
      Refresh();                                               
  }   
    for (pos = servoPosMax[p]; pos >= servoPosMin[p]; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
      servos[p].write(pos);                                       // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
      delay(15);                                                  // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
      Refresh();
    }
  }
}
void Refresh() {
  refresh = refresh ? false : true;                             // set refresh one time / 2
  if (refresh) SoftwareServo::refresh();
  Serial.print("Servo Number = ");
  Serial.println(p);
  Serial.print("  Angle =  ");
  Serial.println(pos);
}
```

Comment: There seems to be something quirky about this, the line "servos[m].write(((servoPosMax[m]+servoPosMin[m])/2));" in Setup() accepts the value but doesn't execute until it runs the void.loop() at the first servo.write command. How can I preset the servo position in void.setup() with this action the way it is??

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively easy fix, you need to change one symbol in the library code, in `Servo.h`:

Change

```
typedef struct  {
   uint8_t nbr        :6 ;
   uint8_t isActive   :1 ;
 } ServoPin_t   ;
```

To

```
typedef struct  {
   uint8_t nbr        :7 ;
   uint8_t isActive   :1 ;
 } ServoPin_t   ;
```

Pull request here: https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Servo/pull/11